# What is the anova variation of a paired t-test in my case?

Tags: anova, t-test, chi-squared-test, repeated-measures

I have the following case:

I inventoried birch trees in 10 areas, once in 2000 and once last year (same areas inventoried in both years). If I want to see if there is a difference in the average amount of living birch trees per hectare between 2000 and 2017 for these 10 areas then I use a paired t-test. Correct?

Now I want to also split the data of these trees in different tree size classes. So e.g. make classes from 5-15 cm, 15-25, 25-35, etc.

I thought of the following questions: 1) Is there a different tree size distribution between 2000 and 2017 for these areas? AND 2) Is there a difference between 2000 and 2017 for these areas in any of the size classes?

Now I was thinking I could answer this first question with some kind of chi-square test (not that I know what kind exactly), and the second with a one-way repeated measures ANOVA. Would this be correct? I was also thinking that if there is a significant difference in any of the classes (indicated by the ANOVA results) then it basically means that the distribution is also different, right?

Can you advise me on what statistical test to use for my data? Please use rather simple language as I might not understand otherwise.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Alwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let x1_i and x2_i be the variable of interest for subject (area) i at points 1 and 2 of time, respectively. Part of the subjects belong to treatment (size class) A and the rest belong to treatment B. The pared t-test is actually a two-sample t-test for differences z_i=y2_i-y_1 between the two "treatments".

The generalization of the paired t-testing procedure to 2 or more treatment groups is the one-way anova for the differences z_i. The paired t-test is just a special case of this procedure, where the number of treatments is 2.

Lauri